# How to estimate missing DV using its own estimation model within a linear model?

Tags: r, missing-data

This question is more about statistics than R programming, though as I am a beginning user of R, I would especially appreciate any thoughts in the context of R; thanks for considering it:

The outcome variable in one of our linear models (lm) is waist circumference, which is missing in about 20% of our dataset.  Last year a model was published which reliably estimates waist circumference from BMI, age, and gender (all of which we do have).  I'd like to use this model to impute the missing waist circumferences in our data, but I'm wanting to make sure I incorporate the known error in that estimation model.  The standard error of the intercept and of each coefficient has been reported.

Could you suggest how I might go about responsibly imputing (or perhaps a better word is estimating) the missing waist circumferences and evaluating any effect on my own waist circumference prediction models?

Thanks again for any coding strategy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more appropriate for stats.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank has indicated, this question has a strong stats flavor to it. But one possible solution does indeed entail some sophisticated programming, so perhaps it's legitimate to put it in an R thread.

In order to "incorporate the known error in that estimation", one standard approach is *multiple imputation*, and if you want to go this route, R is a good way to do it. It's a little involved, so you'll have to work out the specifics of the code for yourself, but if you understand the basic strategy it's relatively straightforward.

The basic idea is that for every subject in your dataset you impute the waist circumference by first using the published model and the BMI, age, and gender to determine the expected value, and then you add some simulated random noise to that; you'll have to read through the publication to determine the numerical value of that noise. Once you've filled in every missing value, then you just perform whatever statistical computation you want to run, and save the standard errors. Now, you create a second dataset, derived from your original dataset with missing values, once again using the published model to impute the expected values, along with some random noise -- since the noise is random, the imputed values for this dataset should be different from the imputed values for the first dataset. Now do your statistical computation, and save the standard errors, which will be a little different than those from the first imputed dataset, since the imputed values contain random noise. Repeat for a bunch of times. Finally, average the saved standard errors, and this will give you an estimate for the standard error incorporating the uncertainty due to the imputation.

What you're doing is essentially a two-level simulation: on a low level, for each iteration you are using the published model to create a simulated dataset with noisy imputed values for missing data, which then gives you a simulated standard error, and then on a high level you repeat the process to obtain a sample of such simulated standard errors, which you then average to get your overall estimate.

This is a pain to do in traditional stats packages such as SAS or Stata, although it IS possible, but it's much easier to do in R because it's based on a proper programming language. So, yes, your question is properly speaking a stats question, but the best solution is probably R-specific.

Comment: @T Thank you for considering this question.  Yes, I'm now envisioning a function containing a loop which imputes missing values, runs the prediction model, saves off the coefficients and SEs; in fact, I could call that function within boot syntax and get the coefficients & SE CI's....  Thanks again for thinking about it.